# Why is AssemblyResolve called when Assembly is in CurrentDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, .net-assembly

I have a situation where `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` is called for an assembly that has already been loaded into the current domain using `Assembly.Load(myAssemblyMemStream.ToArray())`.

Why is that?

I need to do the following to get it to work. How does this differ from what .NET does automatically?

```
Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                    .GetAssemblies()
                    .First(x => x.FullName == args.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load contexts http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx. Loading the byte[] doesn't cause assemblies in other load contexts to be able to see it. It is a security feature.