# Why AssemblyResolver fire even when dll is loaded (manualy)?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I have C# solution with 2 project:

1. DLLTest (Console app)
2. BLib (library)

In DLLTest I set reference to BLib and set Copy Local property to false.
Compile solution.
Copy BLib.dll to 'C:\BLib.dll' and run application.
In first step in my code I load Assembly from path 'C:\BLib.dll' then invoke method from there. On invoking method from BLib assembly fire AssemblyResolver and try load assembly which I loaded before manually.

Can I do something that application to know that the library has already been loaded and not try load it again?
This is **BClass.cs** file from BLib project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BLib
{
    public class BClass
    {
        public static void PrintName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BLib");
        }
    }
}
```

This is **Program.cs** file from DLLTest project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DLLTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
            Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\BLib.dll");
            Console.WriteLine("Loaded assembles:");
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
                .ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));
            Console.WriteLine("End list of assembles");
            try
            {
                PrintMessage();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void PrintMessage()
        {
            BLib.BClass.PrintName();
        }

        private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Name);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find similar question [Why is AssemblyResolve called when Assembly is in CurrentDomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305301/why-is-assemblyresolve-called-when-assembly-is-in-currentdomain) Answer from there follow me to [Choosing a Binding Context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx) where everything was detailed described (row **Neither** column **Disadvantages**).

That I think so, this is security reason.